# How can I check a version of installed ODBC MariaDB connector?

Tags: mariadb, odbc

Several months ago I built MariaDB Connector/ODBC from Source following official instructions:

```
git clone https://github.com/MariaDB/mariadb-connector-odbc.git
cd mariadb-connector-odbc
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo -DCONC_WITH_UNIT_TESTS=Off -DCONC_WITH_MSI=OFF -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local .
cmake --build . --config RelWithDebInfo
```

But I don't remember what version of the Connector I built, so now I need to know it. **How can I check version of MariaDB Connector/ODBC?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`file` won't give much information:

```
file libmaodbc.so
libmaodbc.so: ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=5a3305eade1036378d57e16dcb09e02d541cc6a9, with debug_info, not stripped
```

A run of `strings` and `grep` commands gave me the version quite easily:

```
jynus@sangai:~/Downloads$ strings mariadb-connector-odbc-3.0.9-ga-debian-x86_64/lib/libmaodbc.so | grep -A10 ^_client_version
_client_version
_server_host
_pid
_platform
libmariadb
3.0.9
Linux
x86_64
MYSQL_PWD
5.5.5-
compiled_in
```

However, that doesn't seem to match the release version well:

```
jynus@sangai:~/Downloads$ strings mariadb-connector-odbc-2.0.18-ga-debian-x86_64/lib/libmaodbc.so | grep -A10 ^_client_version
_client_version
_pid
_platform
_server_host
libmariadb
2.3.6
Linux
x86_64
client
MYSQL_PWD
5.5.5-
```

I found another string like this, which seems to match the released version:

```
jynus@sangai:~/Downloads$ strings mariadb-connector-odbc-2.0.18-ga-debian-x86_64/lib/libmaodbc.so | grep ma-
[ma-2.0.18]
jynus@sangai:~/Downloads$ strings mariadb-connector-odbc-3.0.9-ga-debian-x86_64/lib/libmaodbc.so | grep ma-
[ma-3.0.9]
jynus@sangai:~/Downloads$ strings mariadb-connector-odbc-3.1.1-ga-rhel7-x86_64/lib/libmaodbc.so | grep ma-
[ma-3.1.1]
```

Use that command to find the version. Your mileage may vary, there may be a simpler way (e.g. using it), but this is a quick and dirty option.